# Solution of the Lagrange's minimal surface equation

Tags: differential-equations, special-functions

Can I use *Mathematica* to solve the [Lagrange's  partial differential equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangesEquation.html)?

$$(1+f_y^2)f_{xx}-2f_xf_yf_{xy}+(1+f_x^2)f_{yy}=0$$

I tried:

```
pde = (1 + (D[f[x, y], y])^2) D[f[x, y], x, x] - 
2 D[f[x, y], x] D[f[x, y], y] D[f[x, y], x, 
 y] + (1 + (D[f[x, x], y])^2) D[f[x, y], y, y] == 0

soln = DSolve[pde, y[x, y], {x, y}]
```

but it doesn's work.

for instance the plane $Ax+By+C=0$ is a trivial solution to this equations

Comment: It should be `DSolve[pde, f[x, y], {x, y}]` (mind the `f`), but it looks like mma can't solve it.

Comment: There is another problem too: `(D[f[x, x], y]` shold be `(D[f[x, y], y]`

Comment: I doubt that such a general PDE can be handled, unless you give suitable restrictions.